# DYMO Label printing results in "'MediaType' attribute is not declared."

Tags: c#, asp.net, dymo

I have used this method in the past and it worked fine, I do not have any idea what could have been changed down the line to cause this error to start appearing. Here is my current code:

```
var label = DYMO.Label.Framework.Label.Open("OrderLabel.label");
                label.SetObjectText("lblcompany", company);
                label.SetObjectText("lblcustomer", customer);
                label.SetObjectText("lblorder", order);
                label.SaveToFile(Server.MapPath("~/Labels/order.label"));

                Response.ContentType = "label";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = order.label");
                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Labels/order.label"));
                Response.End();
```

The error seems to relate to the first line `DYMO.Label.Framework.Label.Open("OrderLabel.label");`

The documentation on DYMO label printing via asp.net is very scarce and I've searched and searched and only found a couple of references to this specific error. None of which have helped, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to uninstall the DYMO.Label.Framework that I had installed via NuGet Package Manager and download and install the SDK software provided by DYMO from this link:
https://www.dymo.com/en-US/online-support-sdk

This download will add DYMO.Label.Framework.dll which you can then Add a Reference to via Visual Studio. Apparently there is some difference in the version provided via NuGet Package Manager and the one provided in the download from DYMO.